# No puedo realizar calculo de IVA en tabla dinámica

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema con el cálculo de IVA: la tabla se crea de manera dinámica, ingreso el primer valor que es el precio unitario para comenzar el cálculo y lo hace... el problema está en la segunda fila, deja de hacerlo, agradecería mucho su ayuda.

```js
function multiplicar() {
  m1 = document.getElementById("cantidad[]").value;
  m2 = document.getElementById("pu[]").value;
  r = m1 * m2;
  i = (r * 16 / 100)
  resu = r + i;
  document.getElementById("iva[]").value = i;
  document.getElementById("total[]").value = resu;

}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr class="success">
    <th style="text-align: center;">Cant.</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;">Artículo</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;">Marca</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;">Precio Unitario (Sin IVA)</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;">IVA</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;">Total</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="hide"><input class="form-control" type="number" name="idsol_rf[]" id="idsol_rf[]" value="<?php echo $idsl_mtto_rf;?>" readonly></td>
    <td style="width: 80px;"><input class="form-control" type="number" name="cantidad[]" id="cantidad[]" value="<?php echo $cantidad_rf;?>" readonly></td>
    <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="articulo[]" id="articulo[]" value="<?php echo $descripcion_rf;?>" readonly></td>
    <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="marca[]" id="marca[]" value="<?php echo $marca_rf;?>"></td>
    <td style="width: 120px;"><input class="form-control" type="number" step="any" name="pu[]" id="pu[]" onchange="multiplicar();" required></td>
    <td style="width: 120px;"><input class="form-control" type="number" name="iva[]" id="iva[]"></td>
    <td style="width: 150px;"><input class="form-control" type="number" step="any" name="total[]" id="total[]"></td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hola Manuel, deberías editar la pregunta para añadir el código generado en html, en lugar de el PHP que lo genera. De ese modo sería más fácil ayudarte porque se podría ver mejor el problema (que casi podría decir ya que es que tienes IDs duplicados). Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información. Y completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y su funcionamiento general (y con ello ganarás tu primera medalla).

Comment: @Manuel, no funciona porque en la función no especificas en qué fila estas posicionado, para ello debes pasar el evento y con ello determinar la fila, te podre un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias @fwBasic no había contemplado esa parte, en realidad son unos masters! Mil gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para lograr el objetivo que buscas debes pasar a la función la fila donde estás posicionado, una forma de hacerlo es pasar el objeto a la función a través del evento `onchange` y de allí determinar la fila.

Ejemplo:

```js
function multiplicar(el) {
  var fl = el.parentNode.parentNode;
  m1 = fl.querySelector("#cantidad").value;
  m2 = fl.querySelector("#pu").value;
  r = m1 * m2;
  i = (r * 16 / 100)
  resu = r + i;
  fl.querySelector("#iva").value = i;
  fl.querySelector("#total").value = resu;

}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr class="success">
    <th style="text-align: center;">linea</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;">Cantidad</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;">Precio Unitario</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;">Monto IVA</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;">Total</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="hide">1</td>
    <td style="width: 80px;"><input class="form-control" type="number" name="cantidad[]" id="cantidad" value=""></td>
    <td style="width: 120px;"><input class="form-control" type="number" step="any" name="pu[]" id="pu" onchange="multiplicar(this);" required></td>
    <td style="width: 120px;"><input class="form-control" type="number" name="iva[]" id="iva"></td>
    <td style="width: 150px;"><input class="form-control" type="number" step="any" name="total[]" id="total"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="hide">2</td>
    <td style="width: 80px;"><input class="form-control" type="number" name="cantidad[]" id="cantidad" value=""></td>
    <td style="width: 120px;"><input class="form-control" type="number" step="any" name="pu[]" id="pu" onchange="multiplicar(this);" required></td>
    <td style="width: 120px;"><input class="form-control" type="number" name="iva[]" id="iva"></td>
    <td style="width: 150px;"><input class="form-control" type="number" step="any" name="total[]" id="total"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```